# Install Times New Roman in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: fonts

I was trying to install Times New Roman font using the commands

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Now while implementing the first command, an agreement window appears with an `<ok>` at the bottom of the window which I am supposed to press. But unfortunately the `<ok>` has no links and it cannot be pressed or accepted hitting ENTER.

What to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move the selection over `<ok>` so it's highlighted, then press enter.

Answer (score -1):

If you can download it or copy it from another computer, simply make a new folder in your home entitled `.fonts` and paste the fonts inside (the dot before the folder name makes it hidden).